# How to lead state type to StoreEnhancer expected in createStore function of @reduxjs/toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using the [article](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) of Dan Abramov to sync my redux store with browser LocalStorage.

The problem is I am using typescript and when I try to create the store the following way:

```
const store = createStore(
  App,
  persistedState
);
```

(where persistedState is an object type of IStoreState | undefined) then typescript throws an error:

```
Type 'IStoreState' is not assignable to type 'StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown>'.
```

My question is how can I transform my state to StoreEnhancer to succesfully pass it to createStore function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error actually means that `createStore` is matching the wrong overload.  The second argument to `createStore` can be either an `enhancer` or a `preloadedState`.

```
export interface StoreCreator {
  <S, A extends Action, Ext, StateExt>(
    reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
    enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<Ext, StateExt>
  ): Store<S & StateExt, A> & Ext
  <S, A extends Action, Ext, StateExt>(
    reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
    preloadedState?: PreloadedState<S>,
    enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<Ext>
  ): Store<S & StateExt, A> & Ext
}
```

In this case it is a `preloadedState` and should be assignable to `PreloadedState<IStoreState>` which is basically a deep partial of `IStoreState`.  Perhaps you can fix the error by tweaking the return types on your `loadState()` function, but I have a better solution.

---

You can avoid the confusion about which overload to match by using the `configureStore` utility from Redux Toolkit.  You set your `persistedState` as the `preloadedState` property of the store config.  This property is optional so `undefined` is okay.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: App, // can be a reducer or a reducer map object
  preloadedState: persistedState,
});
```

---

You might want to look into the [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) package which implements this idea with lots of configuration options.